# How to Bind a Angular table selection to input fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a Modal that has a table on the left with all the Customers in a table. On the right side are input fields. I need a user to be able to click on a Customer and populate the inputs fields with the Customer property values.

I made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7224YvcOpSHQKWVTe8Wh?p=preview)

My Code

```
 <table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover">
      <tr><th style="font-weight: bold;">Customers</th></tr>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray" class="pointer">
                  <td>{{job.Customers[0].CustomerName}}</td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">C. Name</span>
      <input style="width:400px" ng-model="CustomerName"  type="text" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">C. Address</span>
          <input style="width:390px" ng-model="CustomerAddress" type="text">
 </div>
```

Comment: check your plunkr link, it's not working

Comment: I guess the plunkr is not working because user3919120 doesn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are many way of doing it.

The easiest way is for them to communicate using the same `$scope`, using the same controller,

1. Move your `ng-controller` to a container element that includes the table and the fields.
2. Then I would add a `selectedCustomer` to the `$scope`, in your controller you can initialize the first customer with `$scope.selectedCustomer = $scope.customers[0];`
3. Then change the `ng-model` of the inputs to use the `selectedCustomer` properties `<input ng-model="selectedCustomer.customerAddress" ... />`
4. Now we need to change the `selectedCustomer` to match the one you click on, you can use `ng-click` to execute an expression when an element is clicked.
   `<tr ng-click="setSelectedCustomer(customer)"`.
5. This also means we need the `setSelectedCustomer` function in the scope, so in the controller you can declare the function

   $scope.setSelectedCustomer = function (customer) {
     $scope.selectedCustomer = customer;
   }

Here's a plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9SkOWYEQt5dAGPwKbEOW?p=preview

Note: Instead of adding stuff to the scope, take a look at aliasing the controller and adding stuff to the controller instance. Happy coding.

Comment: @guzart, but if I want to use the same form to add a new customer? what should I do then?

Comment: @th1rdey3 you would need another variable to store the form customer, i.e. the user bound to the form, and the table customer, so that when you click on "New Customer" you set `$scope.formCustomer = getEmptyCustomer();` and when clicking "Edit" you set `$scope.formCustomer = getCustomer(id);` for example.